# Bash Script - Wget Graphical Download Progress

Tags: bash, x11, wget, download

I'm trying to port this code from `wget + zenity` to `wget + kdialog`.
The code with `zenity`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start wget | zenity
# Note the & at the end of the pipe, this allows the script to continue with wget running in the background

wget http://www.zezeniaonline.com/download/downloadlinux 2>&1 | sed -u 's/.* \([0-9]\+%\)\ \+\([0-9.]\+.\) \(.*\)/\1\n# Downloading at \2\/s, ETA \3/' | zenity --progress --title="Downloading File..." 

#Start a loop testing if zenity is running, and if not kill wget
RUNNING=0
while [ $RUNNING -eq 0 ]
do
if [ -z "$(pidof zenity)" ]
then
  pkill wget
  RUNNING=1
fi
done
```

**The Zenity Code Works perfectly**

[image: Zenity + Wget Download Progress]

I need to do the same but with `kdialog`. I'm tried first with the follow code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start wget | kdialog

wget http://www.zezeniaonline.com/download/downloadlinux 2>&1 | sed -u 's/.* \([0-9]\+%\)\ \+\([0-9.]\+.\) \(.*\)/\1\n# Downloading at \2\/s, ETA \3/' | kdialog --progressbar " " --title="Downloading File..." 

#Start a loop testing if zenity is running, and if not kill wget
RUNNING=0
while [ $RUNNING -eq 0 ]
do
if [ -z "$(pidof kdialog)" ]
then
  pkill wget
  RUNNING=1
fi
done
```

**that don't work at all**

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Start wget | kdialog

wget --progress=dot http://www.zezeniaonline.com/download/downloadlinux 2>&1 | fgrep --line-buffered '%' \ | sed -u -r 's:.* ([0-9]+)% .*:\1:' | kdialog --title "Installation" --progressbar " " &

#Start a loop testing if kdialog is running, and if not kill wget
RUNNING=0
while [ $RUNNING -eq 0 ]
do
if [ -z "$(pidof kdialog)" ]
then
  pkill wget
  RUNNING=1
fi
done
```

But the follow errors.
**Yes its downloading, but the "progress" are not "progressing" in the "kdialog"**

[image: KDialog are not progressing]

Comment: I found this sites 

[1](http://nowardev.wordpress.com/2009/09/12/kdialog-qdbus-progress-bar/)
[2](http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/script/wget-com-progressbar-no-kde)

I hope some of that codes works for me

Comment: If you found a solution, could you please post it as an answer instead of in the question?

Comment: Yes , man , that its the idea , share the solution , for the users need that information , and in case i need saw the info again XD .

Comment: @muru : see my answer , that code works , with kdialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here there is my own solution, I have modified a little my old tutorial on my website linked on this page:

this code will try to download my master repository on github

```
    link="https://github.com/nowardev/kde-peace-settings/archive/master.zip" #my own github stuff 
    a=$(kdialog --progressbar "W-Get will  download: Nowardev GitHub Master stuff " 100);sleep 2
    qdbus $a  showCancelButton true

    while read line ;do
    read -r p t <<< "$line"
    echo $p 
    echo $t 
    qdbus $a Set org.kde.kdialog.ProgressDialog value $p

        while [[  $(qdbus  $a wasCancelled) != "false" ]] ; do
            echo "KILLING THE PROCESS AND KDIALOG"
            qdbus $a  org.kde.kdialog.ProgressDialog.close 

            exit
        done


qdbus $a org.kde.kdialog.ProgressDialog.setLabelText "W-Get will  download: Nowardev GitHub Master stuff  time left : $t" 


done< <(wget "$link" 2>&1 |mawk -W interactive '{ gsub(/\%/," "); print int($7)" "$9 }')
```

Comment: Thank you; this is the best solution I could find around so far. It even lets the user to abort download (Cancel) where many fail: download process goes on even after pressing Cancel. The only (minor) problem is that it doesn't autoclose when download is completed. Could it be because `qdbus $a  org.kde.kdialog.ProgressDialog.close` needs updating?

Comment: Any chance of getting this adapted to `curl`, which ensures faster downloads (especially with option `--parallel`)?

Answer (score 2):

Im trying to adapt that source code , this code works , well i just need adapt the parts i really need.

```
#!/bin/bash

kde_download() {
arch=$(uname -m)

case "$arch" in
    x86)    arch="x86"  ;;
    i?86)   arch="x86"  ;;
    amd64)  arch="amd64"    ;;
    x86_64) arch="amd64"    ;;
    * ) echo "Your Arch '$arch' -> Its not supported."  ;;
esac

ThisDIR="$PWD"
TempDir="/tmp"
TITLE="Team Speak 3 Linux Client"
TS3DIR="/opt/TeamSpeak3/Client"
version=$(curl -s http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/ |   grep -Po '(?<=href=")[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2,3}(?=/")' |   sort -Vr | head -1)
URLICON="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3164499/Linux/Iconos/TeamSpeak3.png"
TS3FILE="TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_$arch-$version.run"
TS3CURL="http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/$version"
TS3CF="http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/$version/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_$arch-$version.run"
TARGET="/opt/Utilidades/Prueba"
J=0

# download with output to dialog progress bar
KDIALOG="`kdialog --title "$TITLE" --progressbar "Downloading:<br>$TS3FILE<br>into<br>$TARGET"`"
if grep "^org.kde.kdialog" <<< "$KDIALOG" > /dev/null; then


# KDE4 kdialog and dbus control
autoclose="qdbus $KDIALOG org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set org.kde.kdialog.ProgressDialog autoClose true"
showcancel="qdbus $KDIALOG org.kde.kdialog.ProgressDialog.showCancelButton false"
setprogress="qdbus $KDIALOG org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set org.kde.kdialog.ProgressDialog value"
manualclose="qdbus $KDIALOG org.kde.kdialog.ProgressDialog.close"
wascancelled="qdbus $KDIALOG org.kde.kdialog.ProgressDialog.wasCancelled"


else
# KDE3 kdialog and dcop control
# cut beginning
KDIALOG="${KDIALOG//DCOPRef\(/}"
# cut end
KDIALOG="${KDIALOG//,ProgressDialog\)/}"
autoclose="dcop $KDIALOG ProgressDialog setAutoClose true"
setprogress="dcop $KDIALOG ProgressDialog setProgress"
showcancel="dcop $KDIALOG ProgressDialog showCancelButton false"
manualclose="dcop $KDIALOG ProgressDialog close"
wascancelled="dcop $KDIALOG ProgressDialog wasCancelled"
fi
    $autoclose
    $showcancel
    cd "$TempDir"
    ( wget "$TS3CF" -o /dev/stdout | while read I ; do
    I="${I//*.......... .......... .......... .......... .......... /}"
    I="${I%%%*}"

    # report changes only
    if [ "$I" ] && [ "$J" != "$I" ]; then
    $setprogress $I
    J="$I"
    fi
    done ; $manualclose ; cd "$ThisDIR" ) &

pid="$!"

while [ -d "/proc/$pid/" ]; do
    if [ "`$wascancelled`" = true ]; then
    kill $pid
    kill `ps aux | grep "wget $TS3FILE -o /dev/stdout" | grep -v grep | tr -s ' ' ' ' | cut -f2 -d\ `
    $manualclose
        if [ "$?" != 0 ]; then
        echo "Installation interrupted."
        exit 255
        fi
    fi
sleep 1
done
wait
}

kde_download
```